# Why are svgs not preview rendered in PimCore v6.3.6?

Tags: svg, pimcore

We are using v6.3.6. of pimcore and the SVG image preview is not working. We only see a generic thumbnail in the backend

[image]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you haven't installed the FFMpeg package in the system. Please try to install it.

Here is the command if you are using Linux system as a server.

> sudo apt-get install ffmpeg

Answer (score 0):

Possible solutions:

1) Clear all caches (Symfony + Data)

The CLI for cache clearing might be helpful:

```
  cache:clear                                Clears the cache
  cache:pool:clear                           Clears cache pools
  cache:pool:delete                          Deletes an item from a cache pool
  cache:pool:list                            List available cache pools
  cache:pool:prune                           Prunes cache pools
  cache:warmup                               Warms up an empty cache
```

2) Make sure you have installed all required software: https://pimcore.com/docs/6.x/Development_Documentation/Installation_and_Upgrade/System_Requirements.html

3) Wait some time and clear the browser cache

Is any of those helpful?